# Puerto de red ABIERTO no detectado por RASPBERRY PI 3B+

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry

Me encuentro con la situacion de usar un puerto de red determinado en mi raspberry, para ello he habilitado en mi router el puerto que necesita **(IP del dispositivo, TCP, Rango de puertos, etc)**.

Pero cuando realizo un `nmap -p 55000 192.168.1.41`

PUERTO : Puerto que quiero acceder
IP DE MI DISPOSITIVO : IP local eth0 con ip **192.168.1.41**

Muestra ese puerto como **cerrado/desconocido**

He probado con herramientas como **ufw** pero tampoco...

Comment: ¿No será que la sintaxis debe ser `nmap -p 55000 192.168.1.41`?

Comment: No perdona se me ha olvidado borrar el "IP" del nmap, gracias por darte cuenta !! Pero no, no es por eso

Comment: Bueno, pues a ver, para que el puerto este abierto debe correr "algo" (un servicio normalmente) en él... Si quieres saber lo que esta corriendo escribe "netstat -anp | grep 55000" en la máquina donde este el servicio.  Si no sale nada es que no lo has arrancado o no funciona.  Si sale algo nos lo cuentas.

Comment: He probado ya esa linea de comandos pero no me retornaba ningun resultado de busqueda...

Comment: En mi router he añadido la ip local de mi raspberry junto con el puerto que quiero abrir, en mi raspberry he realizado un nmap a la IP local indicando el puerto para ver si lo detecta como abierto pero nada...

Comment: Entonces es que no tienes nada corriendo en ese puerto, no hay nada a la escucha. El puerto está `abierto` solo si hay algo escuchando, sino permanece cerrado o sin usar.  Vete al raspberry e instala el `netcat` sino esta instalado, y si lo esta dejalo en ejecución mediante `netcat -l 55000` y luego vete a la maquina del nmap y vuelve a probar a ver si te devuelve algo (o usa un `telnet 192.168.1.41 55000` y le escribes cosas que veras en el netcat del raspberry que esta a la escucha).

Comment: Vale genial lo pruebo !! Muchas gracias !!